# jQuery UI - menu inside iframe

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I'm using jQuery UI menu widget to show context menu when user press a right mouse button on the element. Unfortunately this menu element is inside iframe and the iframe is small so the expanded menu is cutted by an iframe. Is there a way to display the menu above an iframe without without cutting the element? Unfortunately I've got big complicated software and it's too hard to move menu element in HTML outside iframe.

Comment: Some runnable code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: Can you include a some sample code or a link?

Comment: If the context menu must come from the iframe, then I doubt it will be straightforward. See (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299808/display-element-outside-of-iframe). We need to see some code to understand what you are trying to do, so we can find some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a following structure in HTML.

```
<iframe src="whatever">
<div id="rowMenu">
</div>
</iframe>
```

and in my Javascript file I am invoking menu() function from jQuery UI library:

```
$("div#rowMenu).menu({
    menus:  "div.rowMenu",
}).css({
    "padding-top": 10,
    "border-radius": "0px 10px 10px",
    "box-shadow": "3px 3px 3px #444",
    position:   "absolute"
}).show();
```

And the problem is because this iframe is so small and when I am expanding the menu it's cut and it is not visible in its entirety. Is there a way to force that menu to display it above iframe?