# Open <div> popup outside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Info:** I was working on it for so long, I have a webpage that contains an `iframe`. Inside that `iframe` i have opened a page (application) from my own site.

**Question:** I'm trying to get the `<div class = "ps-lightbox"> </ div>` inside that `iframe` out of the `iframe`. but i cant figure it out with jQuery..

I know it sounds confusing. But I hope you understand my explanation.

Does anyone know how to fix this? You could save my day..

[Screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1JZw.png) <

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display element outside of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299808/display-element-outside-of-iframe)

Comment: For security purposes, you can only access the iframe internals if the domain name of your site and iframe source is same. Anyone can manipulate an iframe internals in this way which is not good for most of the cases. Imagine if you can get facebook friend list or email from a facebook widget.

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal OP already specified that it is from same origin. Your whole long comment is irrelevant here

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The site and iframe are from the same domain.

Comment: Doing this is not simple. You need the relevant lightbox html and css and script in parent page to make it work then call a parent page function from inside frame to display it

Comment: You can try by placing a function on your parent page and call it from the iframe like `parent.<function>()` and pass the desired output you want on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the elements which are not part of iframe document. But if you have iframe of your own website then window.postMessage can do the trick.

Consider below example:

**mainPage.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener("message", function(evnet){
                 if(event.type === "GET_SOME_ELEMENT"){
                     var iframeWindow = document.getElementsById("iframe1")[0].contentWindow;

                     iframeWindow.postMessage("POST_SOME_ELEMENT", "TARGET_ORIGIN", {element: $(".some-element")}
                 }
             });
       <script/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="some-element"/>
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframePage.html"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframePage.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          if(window.parent){
             window.parent.postMessage("GET_SOME_ELEMENT", "TARGET_ORIGIN");
             window.addEventListener("message", function(evnet){
                 if(event.type === "POST_SOME_ELEMENT"){
                      console.log(event.data.element);
                 }
             });
          }
       <script/>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact question is how to do it with pure JavaScript, not with jQuery.

But I always use the solution that can be found in jQuery's source code. It's just one line of native JavaScript.

For me, it's the best, easily readable and even afaik the shortest way to get the content of the iframe.

**First get your iframe**

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('id_description_iframe');

// or
var iframe = document.querySelector('#id_description_iframe');
```

**And then use jQuery's solution**

```
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

> It works even in the Internet Explorer which does this trick during
>   the `contentWindow` property of the iframe object. Most other browsers
>   use the `contentDocument` property and that is the reason why we proof
>   this property first in this OR condition. If it is not set to try
>   `contentWindow.document`.

**Select elements in iframe**

Then you can usually use `getElementById()` or even `querySelectorAll()` to select the DOM-Element from the `iframeDocument`:

```
if (!iframeDocument) {
    throw "iframe couldn't be found in DOM.";
}

var iframeContent = iframeDocument.getElementById('frameBody');

// or
var iframeContent = iframeDocument.querySelectorAll('#frameBody');
```

**Call functions in the iframe**

Get just the `window` element from `iframe` to call some global functions, variables or whole libraries (e.g. `jQuery`):

```
var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

// you can even call jQuery or other frameworks
// if it is loaded inside the iframe
iframeContent = iframeWindow.jQuery('#frameBody');

// or
iframeContent = iframeWindow.$('#frameBody');

// or even use any other global variable
iframeWindow.myVar = window.myVar;

// or call a global function
var myVar = iframeWindow.myFunction(param1 /*, ... */);
```

**Note**

All this is possible if you observe the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score -1):

This might help you

```
var html = $(".ps-lightbox").contents().find("body").html()
```

And btw, you can get access to iframe's content only from the same origin due to XSS protection

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your code is inside jQuery ready event.

```
// This won't work
$("#iframe").contents().find('.ps-lightbox');



// This will work
$(function() {
  $("#iframe").contents().find('.ps-lightbox');
})
```

Comment: Don't think you understand what OP is asking